# What does each Esper unlock on each board?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

In Final Fantasy XII Zodiac Age, each character can select 2 boards (or classes). Some of these classes have unique spells or nodes that can unlock based on which Espers are unlocked for that board. But only 1 Esper can be unlocked and then it is gone.

I want to spread out my Esper unlocks and not dump them all onto 1 character, but I also want to unlock certain things to balance out my party. I just don't know what unlocks what.

So my question is: What does each Esper unlock on each board?

Comment: The approach I used in my current game was to check everyone's board whenever I got my hands on a new Esper and see what it unlocked, and chose the character accordingly. I am very curious to see the answers on this question to see if this indeed is the best method or if there is an "absolute best" solution.

Comment: @Laf Yeah I agree. I'm currently just checking as I go without unlocking the Espers yet. I'd like to see what my options are!

Comment: Do you want spoilers for non-story related Esper?

Comment: @Wondercricket The Espers don't need to be hidden in my opinion. This is an older game and I think everyone knows that there are other Espers besides the story ones. I want them all in the answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the website [RPGSite.net](https://www.rpgsite.net/feature/5783-final-fantasy-xii-the-zodiac-age-espers-guide-where-to-find-them-and-which-job-license-board-to-use-them-on), the following is an extensive list of each Esper and which licenses they unlock for each job. The website also gives suggestions on which options provide the most benefits based on different combinations, but the decision is ultimately up to you

**Belias, the Gigas**

> 1. Knight: Potion Lore 1
> 2. Foebreaker: Horology technick
> 3. Bushi: Libra technick
>
>    *Suggestion: As Belias is the first Esper in the game, his License Board unlocks are not great and will not add
>          much to your skillsets. Libra is found in many other classes already, and Horology is an awkward Technick based
>          on your game clock, so Potion Lore 1 is our best recommendation.*

**Adrammelech, the Wroth**

> 1. White Mage: Souleater technick, Battle Lore
> 2. Uhlan: Battle Lore
> 3. Time Battlemage: Cura, Raise magicks
> 4. Foebreaker: Battle Lore
> 5. Black Mage: Fumarole, Tumulus equippable
> 6. Bushi: Souleater technick
> 7. Shikari: Shades of Black technick
>
>    *Suggestion: There is no obvious pick here. Time Battlemages do not get access to White Magick otherwise, so
>          giving them Cura and Raise could be useful in a pinch or some additional healing. An extra Battle Lore for you
>          Foebreaker or Uhlan never hurts. Hand Bombs on your Black Mage is probably only useful in very specific builds.
>          Consider if you have a character that can benefit from Adrammelech twice, such as an Uhlan/Time Battlemage.*

**Zalera, the Death Seraph**

> 1. Monk: Traveler technick
> 2. Time Battlemage: Ether Lore 3
> 3. Foebreaker: Traveler technick
> 4. Black Mage: Steal tech, Poach technick
> 5. Bushi: Blood Sword, Karkata equippable
> 6. Shikari: HP+435
>
>    *Suggestion: Traveler deals damage based on the number of steps you've taken since you last used it - not very
>          useful. Having another character able to Steal isn't useful either.  HP+'s aren't as valuable in late-game
>          because Bubble will likely bring your character to 9999 HP regardless. We suggest going with Bushi for
>          additional access to weaponry or Ether Lore for your Time Battlemage. (Blood Sword causes Sap and Karkata causes
>          Confuse on hit)*

**Cúchulainn, the Impure**

> 1. White Mage: Libra technick
> 2. Uhlan: Wither technick
> 3. Machinist: Magick Lore
> 4. Red Battlemage: Firaga, Thundaga, Blizzaga, Sleepga magicks
> 5. Knight: Battle Lore
> 6. Foebreaker: Shades of Black technick
> 7. Bushi: Stamp technick [Also unlocked by Ultima]
> 8. Shikari: Protectga, Shellga magicks
>
>    *Suggestion: The most enticing selection here is more Black Magick for your Red Battlemage. If your Red Battlemage
>          is also your Black Mage (and thus already has those magicks), then we suggest giving Cúchulainn to your
>          Shikari for additional protective buffs.*

**Mateus, the Corrupt**

> 1. Uhlan: Magick Lore (x2)
> 2. Knight: Curaga, Esuna, Cleanse, Regen magicks
> 3. Time Battlemage: HP+230
> 4. Black Mage: Caldera, Volcano equippable
> 5. Shikari: Gil Toss technicks
>
>    *Suggestion: Knights do not gain access to White Magick on their own, and another character able to use
>          Esuna/Cleanse/Regen is probably your best option (unless your Knight is also your White Mage). Gil Toss has its
>          uses, but you probably have plenty of characters who can do that already. The HP+ node is there if nothing else
>          is valuble to your setup.*

**Exodus, the Judge-Sal**

> 1. White Mage: Battle Lore
> 2. Machinist: Oil, Decoy magicks
> 3. Red Battlemage: Platinum Helm, Giant's Helm, Dragon Helm, Platinum Armor, Carabineer Mail, Dragon Mail
>              equippable
> 4. Knight: HP+350
> 5. Monk: Souleater technicks
> 6. Time Battlemage: Battle Lore
> 7. Foebreaker: Magick Lore (x4) [Also unlocked by Zeromus]
> 8. Black Mage: Platinum Helm, Platinum Armor equippable
> 9. Shikari: Stamp tech
> 10. Bushi: HP+500
>
>     *Suggestion: There is no clear winner here. All those heavy armors for your Red Battlemage look enticing, but for
>           end-game purposes, they probably aren't going to be as useful as high-end robes. Still, other options are
>           not much better. The 4 Magic Lores are worth a look if your foebreaker is also a mage and does not already have
>           access to them. As always, consider if you have any job pairings that can benefit from Exodus twice.*

**Zeromus, the Condemner**

> 1. White Mage: HP+270
> 2. Machinist: Makara equippable
> 3. Red Battlemage: Channeling
> 4. Monk: Sight Unseeing technick
> 5. Time Battlemage: Addle technick, Shear technick
> 6. Foebreaker: Magick Lore (x4) [Also unlocked by Exodus]
> 7. Black Mage: Giant's Helm, Carabineer Mail equippable
> 8. Bushi: Magick Lore (x2)
>
>    *Suggestion: Channeling reduces MP cost by 10%, and that's a good thing for your Red Battlemage to have
>          (especially if you gave them Cúchulainn  for higher level Black Magicks). Otherwise, Addle and Shear are
>          especially good debuff technicks you can give to your Time Battlemage. Bushis already get plenty of Magick
>          Lores, but they can get two more if you choose. Plenty of good options here.*

**Chaos, Walker of the Wheel**

> 1. White Mage: Defender, Save the Queen equippable, HP+310
> 2. Uhlan: Aeroga, Bio, Blindga, Silencega magicks
> 3. Machinist: HP+350
> 4. Red Battlemage: Ultima Blade equippable
> 5. Knight: Excalipur, Revive tech, HP+390 [Also unlocked by Zodiark or a Quickening node)
> 6. Monk: Esunaga, Protectga, Shellga, Holy magicks
> 7. Time Battlemage: HP+270
> 8. Archer: Magick Lore
> 9. Bushi: Brawler
>
>    *Suggestion: If you have a Black Mage/Monk, give them Chaos for sure. Holy will be a very useful spell to have and
>          the protective buffs are just a bonus. These are good magicks for your monk to have even if they are not also a
>          Black Mage. Otherwise, the next best options is probably the Uhlan support spells or giving greatswords to your
>          White Mage.*

**Shemhazai, the Whisperer**

> 1. White Mage: HP+230
> 2. Machinist: Caldera, Volcano
> 3. Red Battlemage: Cleanse, Esuna magicks
> 4. Knight: Potion Lore 2
> 5. Monk: Potion Lore 3
> 6. Archer: Dragon Helm, Magepower Shishak, Grand Helm, Dragon Mail, Maximilian, Grand Armor equippable
> 7. Black Mage: Steel Mask, Mirror Mail equippable
> 8. Bushi: Shield Block
> 9. Shikari: Spica, Antares, Arcturus, Fomalhaut equippable
>
>    *Suggestion: Giving Shemhazai to your Archer will allow them to wear the best heavy armors in the game.
>          Giving your Red Battlemage status removing skills will also be sure to come in handy. If your Red Battlemage and
>          your Archer are the same character, then this is an easy choice to make. None of the other selections come
>          close.*

**Ultima, the High Seraph**

> 1. Uhlan: Expose technick
> 2. Machinist: Magick Lore (x3) [Also unlocked by a Quickening node]
> 3. Red Battlemage: Claymore, Defender, Save the Queen equippable
> 4. Knight: Telekinesis tech, Battle Lore
> 5. Monk: Swiftness (x2)
> 6. Time Battlemage: Diamond Sword, Runeblade, Deathbringer, Stoneblade equippable
> 7. Foebreaker: Swiftness
> 8. Archer: Infuse technick, 1000 Needles technick [Also unlocked by Zodiark]
> 9. Black Mage: Telekinesis tech
> 10. Bushi: Stamp tech [Also unlocked by Cúchulainn]
> 11. Shikari: Phoenix Lore (x2)
>
>     *Suggestion: Swiftness is the best passive node in the game (reduces action by 10%). If your Monk does not already
>           have Swiftness, then give them Ultima. If Foebreaker needs the Swiftness, then give them Ultima. If both your
>           Monk and Foebreaker already have Swiftness, then the next best option is probably Expose for your Uhlan. As
>           always, see if you have any characters that can 'double benefit' with Ultima.*

**Zodiark, Keeper of Precepts**

> 1. White Mage: Claymore equippable
> 2. Machinist: HP+390
> 3. Red Battlemage: Ragnarok equippable
> 4. Knight: Excalipur, Revive, HP+390 [Also unlocked by Chaos and a Quickening node]
> 5. Monk: Renew Magick
> 6. Time Battlemage: Durandal, Simha equippable
> 7. Archer: Infuse tech, 1000 Needles tech [Also unlocked by Ultima]
> 8. Bushi: Giant's Helm, Dragon Helm, Magepower Shishak, Carabineer Mail, Dragon Mail, Maximilian equippable
>
>    *Suggestion: Zodiark mostly adds high-level equipment to classes that could not otherwise wield them. Renew is the
>          highest level White Magick that fully heals your team but it is costly to cast. For Zodiark, it is probably best
>          just to see which characters can double up best on the unlocks he provides.*

**Hashmal, Bringer of Order**

> 1. Uhlan: Bonecrusher technick
> 2. Red Battlemage: Steal technick
> 3. Knight: Curaja, Bravery, Faith, Confuse magicks
> 4. Monk: Cura, Raise magick
> 5. Time Battlemage: Channeling
> 6. Foebreaker: Swiftness
> 7. Black Mage: Makara equippable
> 8. Shikari: Bonecrusher technicks
>
>    *Suggestion: Like Mateus, it is probably best to give Hashmal to your Knight in order to give them some White
>          Magick abilities. If your Knight is also your White Mage, then the next best choice is probably Channeling for
>          your Time Battlemage.*

**Famfrit, the Darkening Cloud**

> 1. White Mage: Orichalcum Dirk, Platinum Dagger, Numerology technick
> 2. Uhlan: Potion Lore 3
> 3. Machinist: Hastega, Slowga, Vanishga, Reflectga, Warp, Graviga magicks
> 4. Red Battlemage: Battle Lore (x2)
> 5. Monk: Arise, Dispelga spells
> 6. Time Battlemage: Battle Lore
> 7. Foebreaker: Magick Lore
> 8. Archer: HP+390, HP+435
> 9. Black Mage: HP+190, HP+230, HP+310
>
>    *Suggestion: That's a lot of useful Time Magicks you can give to your Machinist, so that's probably your best bet.
>          Even better if you have a Machinist/White Mage.*

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much Wondercricket

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Of course! Glad I could help :)